# Ecore SCA MetaModel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, .emf, sca

I am looking for an ecore diagram of SCA, I don't want to start from scratch.

The only partial information I get is this diagram picture.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Image:SCAMM.jpg

Thanks for any answers even if they are negatives

ps : I'll try to upload my ecore if I need to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ecore and complete tooling (graphical modelers among others) of SCA is available in Eclipse : http://www.eclipse.org/stp/sca/